# How to Add items to Observable collection, which is inside a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am not able to add items to Observable collection, which is inside a method.

Below is a code:

- I will call GetFeaturelist() method first , here it returns observable collection and then I will call AddRange it should add items to FeatureList inside GetFeaturelist() method which is not happening.

Please help me out to fix this.

```
GetFeaturelist().AddRange(_featureListBuffer);

private ObservableCollection<Feature> GetFeaturelist()
{
   return FeatureList;
}


public class ObservableCollection<T> :    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection.
    /// </summary> 
    public void AddRange( IEnumerable<T> collection )
    {
        foreach( T i in collection )
        {
            Items.Add( i );
        }

        OnCollectionChanged( new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs( NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset ) );
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- Am able to do like this  `FeatureList.AddRange(_featureListBuffer);` 
  and its working fine BUT I wanted like this  `GetFeaturelist().AddRange(_featureListBuffer);`

Comment: "...which is not happening" - I cannot reproduce your problem. The code works fine for me. Maybe you could add some more details? *What* is *not* happening? -- And *what IS* happening?

Comment: Is the `ObservableCollection` returned from `GetFeatureslist()` is __your__ observable collection, or .NET's observable collection?

Comment: @Alex: Somewhat confusing, but you can see that a new class `ObservableCollection<T>` is defined by deriving from the BCL `ObservableCollection<T>` (in a different namespace).

Comment: What do you mean by 'inside' `GetFeatureList()`? `GetFeatureList()` is executed in its entirety before `AddRange` is. ObservableCollection<T> is a reference type, so you should get the behaviour you expect i.e. referring to the same instance in each scope.

Comment: @Martin, Not confusing at all. One of the types derives from the other, but they are not the same type. One has AddRange() and the other one does not. 

Maybe the problem is a compilation problem, and not a runtime problem, as Manasa YB did not specify the exact meaning of "does not happen"

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, misread your comment, but you are right that from the code snippet it is not obvious which collection type is returned. However, I read this question as "I have created my own collection and when using the base collection I don't have access to my extra method."

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks completely valid and it should be working fine.

The only thing I can think of is that you may have a name clash: your "ObservableCollection" has exactly the same name as the base "ObservableCollection" that you derive from. This is very prone to various typos and mis-imports.

If in the place where you define `private ObservableCollection<Feature> GetFeaturelist()` you have `using System.Collections.ObjectModel`, then the method signature may actually think it returns the BASE o-coll, instead of derived one, which you probably wanted it to. In such case, the code would not compile, and the ERRORs windows should clearly state what's wrong.

First, check the usings at the site of the method definition. If they are correct, and if the code compiles properly, then, place breakpoint at the call site and check what collection is actually used. Then if you still have problem, update your post with these data.

Answer (score -1):

`ObervableCollection` don't support `AddRange()` method.